# Jsoup selectors with wildcards

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

I am trying to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to select some text from an HTML document.

The HTML I'm interested in is a part of a form:

```
<input type="text" name="key_12345" value="fizz" id="varz_key_12345" class="inline-edit-field">
<input type="text" name="key_28382" value="buzz" id="varz_key_28382" class="inline-edit-field">
<input type="text" name="key_83838" value="foo" id="varz_key_83838" class="inline-edit-field">
<input type="text" name="key_98383" value="bar" id="doekfeokf" class="inline-edit-field">
<input type="text" name="key_19283" value="widget" id="vars_key_19283" class="inline-edit-field">
...etc.
```

I'm interested in obtaining any `<input>` element whose `id` attribute begins with `varz_key_`. Hence in the example above, I'd be interested in all the inputs except the 4th because its ID doesn't start with `varz_key_`.

The best I've been able to come up with is:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(getHtml());
Elements planVarInputs = doc.select("input[id^=\"varz_key_\"]");
log.info("planVarInputs's size is ${planVarInputs.size()}");
for(Element input : planVarInputs) {
    System.out.println(input.ownText());
}
```

But this gives me the following output:

> planVarInputs's size is 0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you need the quotes for jsoup.  http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Thanks @Joseph Helfert (+1) - so are you suggesting: `doc.select("input[id^=varz_key_]")`?

Comment: yup I would try that and see

Comment: The quotes should not make a difference, if they do, it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock (+1) - you are correct, the quotes don't make a difference.

Comment: tested locally yea it's the quotes that is messing up.  The docs say it is jquery 'like' selectors not exactly one to one.  So I wouldn't call it a bug.